# How to test a LAN based software on multiple machines

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtual, vmware

We have developed a remote monitoring software that works in a lan/wlan network. 
We want to test the product on 50-100 machines. 
I tried VMWare networking, but I could simulate 2 ips on 1 machine.

Tried network simulation tools on internet but nothing seems to work!

Comment: "but I could simulate 2 ips on 1 machine" - what do you mean by that? You couldn't simulate more than 2 IPs on 1 physical machine? You couldn't simulate 2 IPs on 1 machine?

Comment: I got the solution and it works.. You can multiple IPs to a network